How can I revert refusing consent in the 2024 Developer Survey?
I was trying to take the 2024 developer survey, but I mistakenly clicked the no consent in the first question, and now I cannot go to the page again.
Is there any way to change my answer to consent and then take the survey in this case?

I would think clearing the cookies or visiting SO from a private tab should do the job.
